# Service Monitoring in WSO2 BAM not available on clean install

Tags: wso2

The gadget-repo.xml file has the Service Sample-1 included, but it is not rendering on the browser?

```
<resource path="/gadget-server/gadget-repo/gadget-metadata/gadget-0" isCollection="false">
                <mediaType>application/octet-stream</mediaType>
                <properties>
                    <property key="gadgetName">Sample-1 - Services Monitoring</property>

                    <property key="gadgetUrl">/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/gadget-server/gadgets/Sample-1-ServicesMonitoring/serviceMon.xml</property>
                    <property key="defaultGadget">false</property>
                    <property key="gadgetDesc">This is a sample gadget which show you how to display statistics using WSO2Vis. Graph is generated by a sample set of data.</property>
                    <property key="userCounter">0</property>
                    <property key="unsignedUserGadget">false</property>
                    <property key="thumbUrl">/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/gadget-server/gadgets/Sample-1-ServicesMonitoring/thumb/serviceMon-thumb.png</property>
                </properties>
            </resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WSO2 BAM 2.x.x? If so, gadget-repo.xml is no longer used there to render the gadget in the portal dashboard. You can add the respective service statistics toolbox as mentioned in [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Service+Statistics+Toolbox) . You can get more details about the BAM toolbox concept from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Introduction+to+BAM+Toolbox).

Comment: To get to know more details about WSO2 BAM 2.x.x please follow the official documentation on http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/About+BAM